# How do I use a custom command with node graphicmagick?

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

here is how im currently trimming my image with [gm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm)

```
var fs = require('fs')
var gm = require('gm').subClass({imageMagick: true});

gm(PATH)
.trim()
.write('test-output.png', function (err) {
  if (!err) console.log('done');
});
```

But it seems I need to use -fuzz (Use -fuzz to make -trim remove edges that are nearly the same color as the corner pixels.). I cannot figure out how to use this command:

```
gm(PATH)
.out('convert image -fuzz 10 -trim')
.write('test-output.png', function (err) {
  if (!err) console.log('done');
});
```

This does nothing, doesn't even output. the docs aren't very clear on how to format the custom commands. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You just missed small thing that is chaining methods in javascript.

You can do like this

```
gm('kitten.png').fuzz(30, true).trim().write('test-output.png', function(err) {
  if (!err) console.log('done');
});
```

Here true is to tell fuzz in percentage